# Github site not found 404

Tags: github, github-pages

I created a new repo 
`https://github.com/Azambadar/software-developer-portfolio` on GitHub and enabled my site in the settings at the master branch and it showing the following message:

> Your site is ready to be published at
>   https://azambadar.github.io/software-developer-portfolio/

but when I click the link, it showing `404 site not found`.

Repo have index.html file in the root directory and github would setup auto to this file.

Am I missing something ? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It is possible that the recent GitHub service disruption has caused the GitHub Pages build not to happen. 

"We are validating the consistency of information across all data stores. Webhooks and Pages builds remain paused."
-- https://status.github.com/messages (as of 9:18am EST on Oct 22)

I would give it another shot after this issue resolves.

Comment: @KevinJalbert They haven't set it up correctly; they need a repository called `[username].github.io` for GitHub to recognise it.

Comment: @cybermonkey, that's for a _user_ page. A project page should work the way the OP has it set up, assuming they're using the right branch / directory.

Comment: [Pages builds have started again](https://status.github.com/messages), but I'm sure there's quite a backlog.

Comment: @Chris Ah yes, missed that. Have posted an answer because it's likely that others will be asking the same question (and it would be best if they had a central Q&A they can find).

Comment: @cybermonkey project page is set up with master branch which is the only branch/directory, I think its service issue with Github

Comment: @Webappsdeva We've already established that, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub [recently experienced a significant service interruption/failure](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2018/10/22/github-is-down-because-of-data-storage-issues/) due to apparent hardware issues:

> Developer platform GitHub has been down for hours due to data storage
>   issues. According to GitHub’s status message board, the issue began
>   around 10 PM ET on Sunday. Some users are facing login errors while
>   others are not able to see their commits.

The service is back up and running however are still recovering- in the case of Github Pages, [they are still rebuilding Pages](https://status.github.com/messages):

> We have resumed Pages builds and will continue to monitor as we process a delayed
>   backlog of events.

You haven't done anything wrong with configuring your GitHub Projects site and it should start working within the next few hours.